# DataLayer Enhanced ecommerce additional product parameters - how to properly push them?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I am preparing a developer brief to implement Google Tag Manager with Datalayer and Enhanced ecommerce data included in it. I referred to [Google Tag manager Enhanced ecommerce guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions)  and [Enhanced ecommerce data types specification](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#ecommerce-data).

What I want to know is whether the Enhanced ecommerce data pushed via data layer object called "ecommerce" is also available as variables further on in Tag manager, or is it being pushed solely for the purpose of setting up Google Analytics tag in GTM? I want to use those parameters with other tags in GTM also.

The thing is I want to track more parameters about the product for example than the Google Tag manager Enhanced ecommerce guide is specifying. The article says that in order to track more product parameters, you can do that via custom dimensions (     'dimension1': 'Additional parameter'    ), but I assume those parameters are not available as variables in Tag manager later?

So is the correct way to specify those additional parameters outside the data layer object "ecommerce" or inside it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the e-commerce dataLayer for other tags, as long as the push to the dataLayer contains an event (i.e. a key/value pair where the key is "event" and the name is used to create a custom event trigger). Some parts of the e-commerce dataLayer already have an event (i.e. for productClicks it's  {'event': 'productClick'}), others have not (i.e. the e-commerce object for productImpressions). You can then use the e-commerce-object in all tags that are triggered at that event, or after it.

The same goes for any custom dimensions in the dataLayer. You would create the custom dimension in the GA backend in product scope and then add it to each product:

```
dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'productClick',
      'ecommerce': {
        'click': {
          'actionField': {
            'list': 'Search Results'
          }, // Optional list property.
          'products': [{
            'name': "test", // Name or ID is required.
            'id': "1234",
            'price': 12.33,
            'brand': "brand1",
            'category': "category1",
            'dimension1': "customValue1"
          }, {
            'name': "test", // Name or ID is required.
            'id': "1235",
            'price': 9.23,
            'brand': "brand2",
            'category': "category2",
            'dimension1': "customValue4"
          }]
        }
      });
```

You can then access the custom dimension values as part of the product object - e.g. for the custom dimension of the first product you could create a dataLayer variable <s>"ecommerce.products.0.dimension1"</s> ecommerce.click.products.0.dimension1 (that's not a typo - GTM uses an unusual notation for array indicies, namely that you access the index via the dot notation and not via brackets).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! So If I am getting this right, in theory it also could work with pushes without event set (using Tag priorities), but setting an event in the end of the push and triggeting the Custom tags using that event just makes sure that all the data has loaded to dataLayer?

So for the pushes without event, you can just add a custom event in the end and then trigger the custom tags using that event?

Comment: I currently have this test information in the datalayer:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx2ub8axg5geis4/Screenshot%202016-05-28%2021.24.52.png?dl=0

I am trying to pull out a dimension1 as a custom datalayer variable by using "ecommerce.products.0.dimension1" to define a variable as you mentioned, but am unable to do so. The variable (named CD Test) is still displaying default value (not set)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bibrcl1mlha5y3p/Screenshot%202016-05-28%2021.25.11.png?dl=0

I used an event productloaded to trigger the custom tag that it calling the variable.

Comment: Last comment seems incomplete but for the previous yes, to need an event to update the internal state of the dataLayer (the dataLayer is not just an ordinary object, GTM adds a few of it's own methods and properties to it) so that subsequent tags have access to the data.

Comment: Got it, but still am unable to pull out anything from the ecommerce object. Accessing other values that are in the datalayer root fine. Shall I be using Version 1 or 2 ?